# Kerberos Authentication in Racket

Tags: racket, kerberos

I'm trying to access a REST API in Racket, and I need to use Kerberos authentication (similar to `requests-kerberos` in Python).

Is there a way to do this? I'm using the [http-easy](https://docs.racket-lang.org/http-easy/index.html) package but can switch to something else if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a JSON RESET API in Racket, I would refer to:

https://medium.com/chris-opperwall/practical-racket-using-a-json-rest-api-3d85eb11cc2d

This article explains how to do simple HTTP GETs to a JSON REST API, and then parse the JSON response into a form that you can traverse and manipulate in Racket.